# Routing and nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a set of nested resources -- :users and :messages.

```
  resources :users, :only => [:show,:index] do
    resources :messages
  end
```

And also a formtastic form in the "new.html.haml" template for the Message model and it needs to use these resources:

```
=semantic_form_for [@user,@message] do |f|
 =f.input :title
```

The problem is in the actual action path that is generated from [@user,@message], and it looks like this:

```
/users/4cdc7f9dfae434029a0000aa/messages
```

This is wrong because I am using a named route, so this should look like "/users/nickname/messages"

How can I make sure that @user produces a proper path output?

Edit: Here is the name routes I am using to slugify the user.

```
  match "/users/:nickname/messages" => "messages#index"
  match "/users/:nickname/messages/new" => "messages#new", :as=>:new_message
  match "/users/:nickname/messages" => "messages#create", :as=>:create_message
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess what you want is to use the nickname as the url slug. What you need for that is just the regular nested resources;

```
# in routes.rb

resources :users do
  resources :messages
end
```

which would give you the same routes except they would have `:id` instead of `:nickname` in there.

Now for the actual trick that lets you use the user's nickname as the url identifier:

```
# user.rb

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param
    self.nickname
  end
end
```

You would automatically get the nickname in the url, and have it passed on to your controllers as `params[:id]` so you have to act accordingly in your controller

```
# users_controller.rb
…
def show
  @user = User.find_by_nickname(params[:id])
end
…
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
=semantic_form_for :message, :url => create_message_path(:nickname => @user.nickname) do |f|
  # ...
```